# Android NullPointerException when trying to display an intent message for an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I see a run time error at this line of code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

textView.setText(message);
```

exception I am getting,

```
error:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: your textview is not initialized. Please check that you have initialized your view before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done setcontentview(R.layout.xxx)?

Either you havent done this or you dont have a view called textView in your layout. You can post more code.